# PHP Form Data Checking Submit Button Name

Tags: php, forms, post

I have two forms on the same page, each with different fields and different submit button names.

```
<button type="submit" name="formOne">Submit form</button>
<button type="submit" name="formTwo">Submit form</button>
```

On my `mailer.php` page I would like to check which submit button has been clicked, and process the code accordingly.

The code I have so far works for a single form, as follows;

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" ) {
    // my form 1 data
    // do stuff
}
```

However I thought I coulld add an `if/else` to check which submit button was clicked, something like;

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" ) {
    if($_POST['formOne']){
        // form 1 data
        // my form 1 data
        // do stuff
    }
    if($_POST['formTwo']){
        // form 2 data
        // my form 2 data
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

This doesn't seem to work. The error I receive is;

> Notice: Undefined index: formOnein ... line 7

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want, you can alternatively use hidden inputs. You can access hidden inputs from php just like a normal text input.

```html
<form method="GET" action="https://postman-echo.com/get">
    <input type="hidden" name="form" value="one" />
    <button type="submit">Submit form</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot to check if the var `isset()`.

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" ) {
    if(isset($_POST['formOne'])){
        // form 1 data
        // my form 1 data
        // do stuff
    }
    if(isset($_POST['formTwo'])){
        // form 2 data
        // my form 2 data
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, when I use this my form data doesn't send. Although I do see a Status Code: 200 OK in devtools. Any ideas?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the form posting, just stops a warning coming up when you access a non-existant array key! Try `var_dump($_POST);exit;` to see what the form sends.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

`<button type="submit" name="formOne">Submit form</button>
<button type="submit" name="formTwo">Submit form</button>`

use

```
<input type="submit" name="formOne" value="Submit Form"/>
<input type="submit" name="formTwo" value="Submit Form"/>
```

php code:-

```
 <? if(isset($_POST['formOne'])){echo "form One";} elseif(isset($_POST['formTwo'])){echo "form Two"; }?>
```